# Can't import in python

Tags: python, import

Sorry, I am a bit new to this language

I am trying to import [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) into my program like this

```
from gooey import Gooey
@Gooey
def main():
    rest of code
```

but my console says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robertan111\workspace\test\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gooey import Gooey
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gooey\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gooey.python_bindings.gooey_decorator import Gooey
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gooey\python_bindings\gooey_decorator.py", line 50, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I don't even know what wx is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't made all that clear by the Gooey project, but their [`setup.py` setup stript](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/blob/master/setup.py#L22) includes the line:

```
dependency_links = ["http://www.wxpython.org/download.php"],
```

You'll need to download and install wxPython project (which provides the `wx` package) from http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

The `dependency_links` list is not the place to put such information; they should really add that to their installation instructions.